The installation of the. inf file encountered an issue where the system could not find the specified file
I want to convert a HID interface USB plug and play device to a VISA type serial port in Labview. I checked the website
Link
Link
My inf file looks like this
;===========================================================================
;  This file was generated using:
;  NI-VISA Driver Development Wizard version 5.3
;===========================================================================
;
;  This file is for use with Windows 8/7/Vista. This will not work on Windows
;  XP.  This Windows Setup Information File contains the information
;  NI-VISA needs in order to access your instrument.  Do not modify the
;  contents of this file unless you are sure about what you are doing.
;
;===========================================================================
;
;  Windows Vista/7 Installation:
;  To apply the contents of this file to a system's settings, right-click
;  this file and choose "Install". If the device was plugged in before this
;  file is installed, the device will need to be removed from the "Unknown
;  Devices" class in the Windows Device Manager.
;
;===========================================================================
;
;  Windows 8 Installation:
;  To apply the contents of this file to a system's settings, a catalog file
;  must be generated and signed using either a personal certificate or a
;  certificate obtained from a Certificate Authority (CA).  For detailed
;  instructions on how to install your INF on Windows 8, visit
;  http://ni.com/info and enter the Info Code INFWin8.
;
;===========================================================================
;
;  Removal:
;  At installation, Windows copies the file into the %SystemRoot%\inf
;  directory using the alternate filename oem##.inf.  You may have
;  to search all the files to find the one from which this is copied.
;  Remove that file and its associated .pnf file (if it exists) from
;  %SystemRoot%\inf.  Either reboot the computer, or perform a
;  "Scan for hardware changes" from the Windows Device Manager.
;
;===========================================================================

[Version]
Signature=$WINDOWS NT$
Class=visaUsbDevice
ClassGUID={A3330EDF-239D-4206-833B-1D58952613D5}
Provider=%Vendor0%
DriverVer=04/12/2024,1.0.0.0
CatalogFile.NTx86=prefixx86.cat
CatalogFile.NTIA64=prefixia64.cat
CatalogFile.NTAMD64=prefixamd64.cat
PnpLockdown = 1

;===========================================================================
;  Default Installer
;===========================================================================

;[DefaultInstall]
;CopyINF=prefix.inf


; ================= Source Media Section =====================

;[7]
[SourceDisksNames]
1 = %DISK_NAME%,,,

[SourceDisksFiles.x86]
WinUSB1.sys=1

[SourceDisksFiles.ia64]
WinUSB1.sys=1

[SourceDisksFiles.arm64]
WinUSB1.sys=1

[SourceDisksFiles.amd64]
WinUSB1.sys=1

[DestinationDirs]
LaLa_CopyFiles = 17,prefix\temp

;————————————————
;
;                           版权声明：本文为博主原创文章，遵循 CC 4.0 BY-SA 版权协议，转载请附上原文出处链接和本声明。
;原文链接：https://blog.csdn.net/jt6562/article/details/9032131

;===========================================================================
;  Class Installer
;===========================================================================

[ClassInstall32]
AddReg=AddClass_AddReg
CopyFiles=LaLa_CopyFiles

[AddClass_AddReg]
HKR,,,0,%DeviceClassString%
HKR,,Icon,,"-20"

;===========================================================================

[Manufacturer]
%Vendor1%=USBList,NTx86,NTamd64

[USBList.NTx86]
%USB\VID_1A86&PID_E429.DeviceDesc%=WinUsb_Inst, USB\VID_1A86&PID_E429

[USBList.NTamd64]
%USB\VID_1A86&PID_E429.DeviceDesc%=WinUsb_Inst, USB\VID_1A86&PID_E429

;[PreCopySection]

[WinUsb_Inst]
Include = winusb.inf
Needs = WINUSB.NT

[WinUsb_Inst.hw]
AddReg=WinUsb_Inst_HW_AddReg

[WinUsb_Inst.Services]
Include = winusb.inf
Addservice = WinUsb, 0x00000002, WinUsb_AddService

[WinUsb_AddService]
DisplayName    = %WinUsb_Service_DisplayName%
ServiceType    = %SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER%
StartType      = %SERVICE_DEMAND_START%
ErrorControl   = %SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL%
ServiceBinary  = %12%\WinUSB.sys

[WinUsb_Inst_HW_AddReg]
HKR,,DeviceInterfaceGUIDs, 0x10000,"{761ED34A-CCFA-416b-94BB-33486DB1F5D5}"
HKR,,NoSetupUI,,1


[LaLa_CopyFiles]
WinUSB1.sys

[Strings]
Vendor0="WWW.WCH.CN"
Vendor1="WWW.WCH.CN"
USB\VID_1A86&PID_E429.DeviceDesc="WCH UART TO KB-MS_V1.7"
DeviceClassString="NI-VISA USB Devices"
WinUsb_Service_DisplayName="WinUSB Driver"
DISK_NAME="USB Device Install Disk"

SERVICE_BOOT_START = 0x0
SERVICE_SYSTEM_START = 0x1
SERVICE_AUTO_START = 0x2
SERVICE_DEMAND_START = 0x3
SERVICE_DISABLED = 0x4

SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER = 0x1
SERVICE_ERROR_IGNORE = 0x0
SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL = 0x1
SERVICE_ERROR_SEVERE = 0x2
SERVICE_ERROR_CRITICAL = 0x3



The setupapi.dev.log is like this
>>>  [Device Install (DiInstallDriver) - C:\Windows\INF\prefix\prefix.inf]
>>>  Section start 2024/04/24 16:37:38.154
      cmd: "C:\WINDOWS\System32\InfDefaultInstall.exe" "C:\Windows\INF\prefix\prefix.inf"
     ndv: Flags: 0x00000000
     ndv: INF path: C:\Windows\INF\prefix\prefix.inf
     dvs: {DrvSetupInstallDriver - C:\Windows\INF\prefix\prefix.inf}
     dvs:      Flags: 0x00000000
     dvs:      {Driver Setup Import Driver Package: C:\Windows\INF\prefix\prefix.inf} 16:37:38.159
     sto:           {Copy Driver Package: C:\Windows\INF\prefix\prefix.inf} 16:37:38.196
     sto:                Driver Package = C:\Windows\INF\prefix\prefix.inf
     sto:                Flags          = 0x00000007
     sto:                Destination    = C:\Users\yunan\AppData\Local\Temp\{b5dbe224-8591-8a47-a39e-de06dacd3195}
     sto:                Copying driver package files to 'C:\Users\yunan\AppData\Local\Temp\{b5dbe224-8591-8a47-a39e-de06dacd3195}'.
     flq:                {FILE_QUEUE_COMMIT} 16:37:38.200
     flq:                     Copying 'C:\Windows\INF\prefix\prefixamd64.cat' to 'C:\Users\yunan\AppData\Local\Temp\{b5dbe224-8591-8a47-a39e-de06dacd3195}\prefixamd64.cat'.
     flq:                     Copying 'C:\Windows\INF\prefix\prefix.inf' to 'C:\Users\yunan\AppData\Local\Temp\{b5dbe224-8591-8a47-a39e-de06dacd3195}\prefix.inf'.
     flq:                {FILE_QUEUE_COMMIT - exit(0x00000000)} 16:37:38.210
     sto:           {Copy Driver Package: exit(0x00000000)} 16:37:38.210
     ump:           Import flags: 0x00040000
     pol:           {Driver package policy check} 16:37:38.286
     pol:           {Driver package policy check - exit(0x00000000)} 16:37:38.286
     sto:           {Stage Driver Package: C:\Users\yunan\AppData\Local\Temp\{b5dbe224-8591-8a47-a39e-de06dacd3195}\prefix.inf} 16:37:38.292
     inf:                Provider       = WWW.WCH.CN
     inf:                Class GUID     = {a3330edf-239d-4206-833b-1d58952613d5}
     inf:                Driver Version = 04/12/2024,1.0.0.0
     inf:                Catalog File   = prefixamd64.cat
     inf:                Version Flags  = 0x00000013
     inf:                {Query Configurability: C:\Users\yunan\AppData\Local\Temp\{b5dbe224-8591-8a47-a39e-de06dacd3195}\prefix.inf} 16:37:38.311
     inf:                     Driver package 'prefix.inf' is configurable.
     inf:                {Query Configurability: exit(0x00000000)} 16:37:38.312
     flq:                {FILE_QUEUE_COMMIT} 16:37:38.316
     flq:                     Copying 'C:\Users\yunan\AppData\Local\Temp\{b5dbe224-8591-8a47-a39e-de06dacd3195}\prefixamd64.cat' to 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{ff536d90-c2db-9f43-b4fd-d5df6a951b13}\prefixamd64.cat'.
     flq:                     Copying 'C:\Users\yunan\AppData\Local\Temp\{b5dbe224-8591-8a47-a39e-de06dacd3195}\prefix.inf' to 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{ff536d90-c2db-9f43-b4fd-d5df6a951b13}\prefix.inf'.
     flq:                {FILE_QUEUE_COMMIT - exit(0x00000000)} 16:37:38.330
     sto:                {DRIVERSTORE IMPORT VALIDATE} 16:37:38.332
     sig:                     Driver package catalog is valid.
     sig:                     {_VERIFY_FILE_SIGNATURE} 16:37:38.381
     sig:                          Key      = prefix.inf
     sig:                          FilePath = C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{ff536d90-c2db-9f43-b4fd-d5df6a951b13}\prefix.inf
     sig:                          Catalog  = C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{ff536d90-c2db-9f43-b4fd-d5df6a951b13}\prefixamd64.cat
!    sig:                          Verifying file against specific (valid) catalog failed.
!    sig:                          Error 0x800b0109: A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.
     sig:                     {_VERIFY_FILE_SIGNATURE exit(0x800b0109)} 16:37:38.410
     sig:                     {_VERIFY_FILE_SIGNATURE} 16:37:38.415
     sig:                          Key      = prefix.inf
     sig:                          FilePath = C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{ff536d90-c2db-9f43-b4fd-d5df6a951b13}\prefix.inf
     sig:                          Catalog  = C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{ff536d90-c2db-9f43-b4fd-d5df6a951b13}\prefixamd64.cat
     sig:                          Success: File is signed in Authenticode(tm) catalog.
     sig:                          Error 0xe0000241: The INF was signed with an Authenticode(tm) catalog from a trusted publisher.
     sig:                     {_VERIFY_FILE_SIGNATURE exit(0xe0000241)} 16:37:38.458
     sto:                {DRIVERSTORE IMPORT VALIDATE: exit(0x00000000)} 16:37:38.460
     sig:                Signer Score  = 0x0F000000 (Authenticode)
     sig:                Signer Name   = NIUSBCert
     sto:                {Core Driver Package Import: prefix.inf_amd64_04796a2e23e72e2f} 16:37:38.463
     sto:                     {DRIVERSTORE IMPORT BEGIN} 16:37:38.463
     sto:                     {DRIVERSTORE IMPORT BEGIN: exit(0x00000000)} 16:37:38.463
     cpy:                     {Copy Directory: C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\Temp\{ff536d90-c2db-9f43-b4fd-d5df6a951b13}} 16:37:38.464
     cpy:                          Target Path = C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\prefix.inf_amd64_04796a2e23e72e2f
     cpy:                     {Copy Directory: exit(0x00000000)} 16:37:38.466
     idb:                     {Register Driver Package: C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\prefix.inf_amd64_04796a2e23e72e2f\prefix.inf} 16:37:38.476
     idb:                          Created driver package object 'prefix.inf_amd64_04796a2e23e72e2f' in DRIVERS database node.
     idb:                          Created driver INF file object 'oem159.inf' in DRIVERS database node.
     idb:                          Registered driver package 'prefix.inf_amd64_04796a2e23e72e2f' with 'oem159.inf'.
     idb:                     {Register Driver Package: exit(0x00000000)} 16:37:38.481
     idb:                     {Publish Driver Package: C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\prefix.inf_amd64_04796a2e23e72e2f\prefix.inf} 16:37:38.481
     idb:                          Activating driver package 'prefix.inf_amd64_04796a2e23e72e2f'.
     cpy:                          Published 'prefix.inf_amd64_04796a2e23e72e2f\prefix.inf' to 'oem159.inf'.
     idb:                          Indexed 2 device IDs for 'prefix.inf_amd64_04796a2e23e72e2f'.
     sto:                          Flushed driver database node 'DRIVERS'. Time = 0 ms
     sto:                          Flushed driver database node 'SYSTEM'. Time = 0 ms
     idb:                     {Publish Driver Package: exit(0x00000000)} 16:37:38.490
     sto:                     {DRIVERSTORE IMPORT END} 16:37:38.490
     dvi:                          Flushed all driver package files to disk. Time = 0 ms
     sig:                          Installed catalog 'prefixamd64.cat' as 'oem159.cat'.
     sto:                     {DRIVERSTORE IMPORT END: exit(0x00000000)} 16:37:38.497
     sto:                {Core Driver Package Import: exit(0x00000000)} 16:37:38.497
     sto:           {Stage Driver Package: exit(0x00000000)} 16:37:38.499
!!!  dvs:           Failed to find driver package after import. Error = 0x00000002
     dvs:      {Driver Setup Import Driver Package - exit (0x00000002)} 16:37:38.611
     sto:      {Delete Driver Package: C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\prefix.inf_amd64_04796a2e23e72e2f\prefix.inf} 16:37:38.611
     sto:           Driver Package = prefix.inf_amd64_04796a2e23e72e2f
     sto:           Flags          = 0x00000000
     ump:           Delete flags: 0x00000000
     pol:           {Driver package policy check} 16:37:38.619
     pol:           {Driver package policy check - exit(0x00000000)} 16:37:38.619
     sto:           {Unstage Driver Package: C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\prefix.inf_amd64_04796a2e23e72e2f\prefix.inf} 16:37:38.622
     inf:                Provider       = WWW.WCH.CN
     inf:                Class GUID     = {a3330edf-239d-4206-833b-1d58952613d5}
     inf:                Driver Version = 04/12/2024,1.0.0.0
     inf:                Catalog File   = prefixamd64.cat
     inf:                Version Flags  = 0x00000013
     sto:                {Core Driver Package Delete: prefix.inf_amd64_04796a2e23e72e2f} 16:37:38.625
     sto:                     {DRIVERSTORE DELETE BEGIN} 16:37:38.625
     sto:                     {DRIVERSTORE DELETE BEGIN: exit(0x00000000)} 16:37:38.626
     idb:                     {Unpublish Driver Package: C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\prefix.inf_amd64_04796a2e23e72e2f\prefix.inf} 16:37:38.627
     idb:                          Clearing active driver package 'prefix.inf_amd64_04796a2e23e72e2f'.
     cpy:                          Unpublished 'oem159.inf'.
     idb:                          Deindexed 2 device IDs for 'prefix.inf_amd64_04796a2e23e72e2f'.
     sto:                          Flushed driver database node 'DRIVERS'. Time = 0 ms
     sto:                          Flushed driver database node 'SYSTEM'. Time = 0 ms
     idb:                     {Unpublish Driver Package: exit(0x00000000)} 16:37:38.632
     idb:                     {Unregister Driver Package: C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\prefix.inf_amd64_04796a2e23e72e2f\prefix.inf} 16:37:38.634
     idb:                          Unregistered driver package 'prefix.inf_amd64_04796a2e23e72e2f' from 'oem159.inf'.
     idb:                          Deleted driver package object 'prefix.inf_amd64_04796a2e23e72e2f' from DRIVERS database node.
     idb:                          Deleted driver INF file object 'oem159.inf' from DRIVERS database node.
     idb:                     {Unregister Driver Package: exit(0x00000000)} 16:37:38.637
     cpy:                     {Delete Directory: C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\prefix.inf_amd64_04796a2e23e72e2f} 16:37:38.638
     cpy:                     {Delete Directory: exit(0x00000000)} 16:37:38.640
     sto:                     {DRIVERSTORE DELETE END} 16:37:38.640
     sig:                          Uninstalled catalog 'oem159.cat'.
     sto:                     {DRIVERSTORE DELETE END: exit(0x00000000)} 16:37:38.644
     sto:                {Core Driver Package Delete: exit(0x00000000)} 16:37:38.644
     sto:           {Unstage Driver Package: exit(0x00000000)} 16:37:38.644
     sto:      {Delete Driver Package: exit(0x00000000)} 16:37:38.648
!!!  dvs:      Failed to import driver packages under 'C:\Windows\INF\prefix\prefix.inf'. Error = 0x00000002
     dvs: {DrvSetupInstallDriver - exit(00000002)}
<<<  Section end 2024/04/24 16:37:38.650
<<<  [Exit status: FAILURE(0x00000002)]


I have created the corresponding .cat file and certificate file as stated on the website
I also asked the corresponding question on this website, but no one answered.
Link
My research and development operating system is Win11, and the target machine is Win10
I think my inf file was written incorrectly. How should I make specific modifications? Do you have any experts in this field? Thank you for any response
I'm trying
1/Write the [DestinationDirs] section of the. inf file and copy the %12%\WinUSB.sys file to the installation directory.
2/Delete the [WinUsb-AddService] section
3/Set permissions in C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository to manually create folder prefix.inf.amd64:04796a2e23e72e2f, and copy the prefix.inf and prefixamd64.cat files into it.
I hope to see that the installation was successful, but not yet.

Who can use ChatGPT to input my INF file and test its errors? Use AI to solve technical problems. ChatGPT is prohibited in China.
